# how to write 4K size file on remote server in python

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, boto, fabric

I am trying to write 50 4KB files on a EC2 instance with S3 mounted on it.

How can I do this in python?

I am no sure how to proceed with this.

Comment: What do you mean, you have s3 mounted on your EC2 instance?  I don't understand that.  Also, do you have any code that you are trying to use?  If so, show it as well as the errors you are receiving.

Comment: Please provide more details about what you are trying to accomplish and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the S3 object bucket mounted via FUSE or some other method to get S3 object space as a pseudo file system, then you write files just like anything else in Python.

```
with open('/path/to/s3/mount', 'wb') as dafile:
    dafile.write('contents')
```

If are you trying to put objects in S3 from an EC2 instance, then you will want to follow the boto documentation on how to do this.

to start you off:

```
create a /etc/boto.cfg or ~/.boto file like the boto howto says

from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

conn = S3Connection()
# if you want, you can conn = S3Connection('key_id_here, 'secret_here')
bucket = conn.get_bucket('your_bucket_to_store_files')
for file in fifty_file_names:
    bucket.new_key(file).set_contents_from_file('/local/path/to/{}'.format(file))
```

This assumes you are doing fairly small files, like you said 50k.  Larger files may need to be split/chunked.